# calculate string length excluding the null character without using library functions in c++?

Tags: c++, string, function

I am a c++ beginner and I am struggling to produce a program for the following assignment:

*Create a project called “StringLength”. The main program should include a function (called findStringLength) which will calculate the length of a string (that is, the number of characters in the string, excluding the terminating null character).
The main program should test the operation of the function with the following test strings:
"Short string"
"A longer string used for test purposes"
""
" "
Declare four character arrays and assign these test values. The output of the program should take the form shown below for each test string:
Length of "Short" = 5
You should write the code to calculate the length of the string yourself; do not use any of the library functions to do this.
Note that if a quotation mark " is to be included in the string, it should be preceded by a backslash \ character – to prevent it from being interpreted as the end of the string:
"Quotation char \" in string"
will be displayed as:
Quotation char " in string*

My code is as follows:

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    size_t findStringLength (char*);

    int main()
    {
        char n1[] = "Short string";
        char n2[] = "A longer string is used for test purposes";
        char n3[] = "";
        char n4[] = " ";
        int stringlength;


        stringlength = findStringLength("Short string/");

        cout << "Length of " << n1 << " = " << stringlength << endl;

        stringlength = findStringLength("A longer string used for test    purposes/");

        cout << "\nLength of " << n2 << " = " << stringlength << endl;

        stringlength = findStringLength("/");

        cout << "\nLength of " << n3 << " = " << stringlength << endl;

        stringlength = findStringLength(" /");

        cout << "\nLength of " << n4 << " = " << stringlength << endl;

        cout << "\n";

    }

    size_t findStringLength (char string[])
    {
        int i=0;
        while(string[i])i++;
        return i;
    }
```

*EDIT* I now have the code shown above, which gives the correct output to a certain extent.  Problem being I receive this

error:H:\StringLength\main.cpp:16: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
     stringlength = findStringLength("Short string/");
                                                    ^

Comment: make your post shorter!

Comment: The declaration and definition of `findStringLength` have different types, that's important.

Comment: Also, don't use the C tag for C++ questions.  C can do several things that C++ can't and vice-versa.

Comment: You have to find it yourself or else you won't learn. But as Mooing Duck said, check your definition and declaration of findStringLength

Comment: Time to talk to a colleague or your tutor.

Comment: sorry about the long post.  I have spoken to my lecturer prior to this but at the moment I feel that the only way I will learn how to understand it is through actually seeing a correctly written code so I can compare to my own.

Comment: _`int findStringLength (string)`_ How is this supposed being a valid function signature?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a simple while loop instead:

```
int string_length = 0;
while (input_str[string_length] != '\0') { string_length++; }

return string_length;
```

It iterates along the string until it hits a null character.

Answer (score 0):

The function can be written in many ways. For example

```
size_t findStringLength( const char *s )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    while ( s[n] != '\0' ) ++n;

    return n;
}
```

Take into account that you call the function for character arrays (as it is described in your assignment). So your function declaration

```
char findStringLength (char);
```

is wrong because the parameter is not declared as a character array or a pointer to first element of a character array. Also you specified a wrong return type.

These two function declarations are equivalent

```
size_t findStringLength( const char s[] );
size_t findStringLength( const char *s );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer the following doubt of yours

**I also receive a repetitive error in conversion from char* to char.**

=> that's actually the error you are getting because of the way you are passing your string to the function which is declared as:

```
char findStringLength (char);
```

and what you are passing is actually n1,n2,etc which are actually arrays of type char and not the character string itself.you should read more about passing of arguments to functions in c++ and for this case you have to pass it by value so better declare your function as:

```
char findStringLength (char*);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int findStringLength (char string[])
{
int i=0;
while(string[i])i++;
return i;
}
```